# 404 not found when posting data with angular2

Tags: angular, http-post, angular2-http, lite-server

I am currently developing a web application with angular2. I followed the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial to get the basics. So, my local server setup and application architecture is the same one.

I now need to perform a **POST request to a static file**. I managed to get the request sent, but the server answers 404 not found. Inspecting the network requests with Firebug, i can see this:

[image]

This is really weird, since the file exists and the url is correct. In fact, if I paste it in a browser (and perform a GET request), i can retrieve the json correctly.

I think that this could be caused by bad server end configuration. As the angular2 tutorial, i am using lite-server, but something is wrong.

Any clue?

Comment: What do you mean by "POST request to a static file". What do you expect to happen by this request. A `POST` request is usually to be processed by the server. A `GET` request can usually just load some existing file if it's served by the server under the requested path.

Comment: What don't you use a `GET` request from your code as well if this is working?

Comment: Hi Gunter. The request needs to be a POST, because in the future it will be processed by the server as you said. I am just using the json file to simulate the server response.

Comment: I guess you need special server support for `POST` requests to static files. Haven't tried this myself yet and I don't know lite-server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you want exactly do, must it seems that there is a little incomprehension somewhere.

I you do a HTTP POST request, is it because you want to modify a resource present on the server ? If this the case, you would need to host a script on your server and not a simple static file.
I you do not want to update the resource, but only want to query it, then you can access to your static file by making a HTTP GET request.

```
this.http
  .get('static/cambio-icona.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(icona => this.icona = icona);
```

Comment: The point is the following.
I need to develop a API that listens to both GET and POST requests from the client. Anyway, i am still developing the front end and, as i use to do, i simulate such server responses with mock json files.
For company related purposes, I need to get the front end working before starting to develop the back end. I used this mock-json strategy many times in the past (mostly with Backbone.js)

Comment: And yes, this call needs to modify a resource on the server. "cambio-icona" stands for "change-icon".